# Strange SELECT error code

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ho threre. When I run a simple select on some tables like:

```
SELECT
    ValidoDa, 
    Tab_Ticket_Default,
    * 
FROM 
    Dipendente_Stor
WHERE 
    CodiceAbi = '08753' and 
    Matricola = 98
order by 
     ValidoDa
```

I can get the error "Ambiguous column name 'ValidoDa'"

What is the reason? There is only one filed called ValidoDa!

can you explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ORDER BY will first attempt to resolves SELECT column list.

In this case, you have `ValidoDa` twice therefore it is ambiguous

You can fix it like this with an alias, but `SELECT *` is bad practice anyway

```
SELECT
    ValidoDa AS ValidoDaFOO, 
    Tab_Ticket_Default,
    * 
FROM 
    Dipendente_Stor
WHERE 
    CodiceAbi = '08753' and 
    Matricola = 98
order by 
     ValidoDa 
     -- or ValidoDaFOO
```

Answer (score 4):

There is one column with this name but you show it twice in the `SELECT` list!

This is not a problem per se, SQL allows that (although I think this is a major design flaw of the language).

The problem resurfaces when you try to use that column in the `ORDER BY` clause. Now (that there are two columns with same name) SQL complains that it can't know which one you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are selecting the field ValidoDa twice - once explicitly, and then again with the *.

Try

```
SELECT     ValidoDa,      
  Tab_Ticket_Default,     
  *  
FROM      
  Dipendente_Stor 
WHERE      
  CodiceAbi = '08753' 
  and      
  Matricola = 98 
order by       
   1
```

Or

```
SELECT     ValidoDa,      
  Tab_Ticket_Default,     
   ** all the other fields of Dipendente_Stor **
FROM      
  Dipendente_Stor 
WHERE      
  CodiceAbi = '08753' 
  and      
  Matricola = 98 
order by       
   ValidoDa
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that saying

```
order by ValidoDa
```

SQL doesn't know which field to use: the explicit `ValidoDa` or the `*.ValidoDa`. If you really need the `*` (I would remove it) then call the first ValidoDa with an alias:

```
SELECT
    ValidoDa AS DaQuando, 
    Tab_Ticket_Default,
    * 
FROM 
    Dipendente_Stor
WHERE 
    CodiceAbi = '08753' and 
    Matricola = 98
order by 
     DaQuando
```